# Facebook Reactions total count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the response from the Graph API on the total count of each reactions in the JSON Response.

For example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "like": 1242,
    "wow": 674,
    "sad": 2500
    ......
  }
}
```

Currently I have the following "{postID}/reactions/?fields=type" But this is not returning the count for each. Does anyone have a solution to this for the recent update in the Facebook API?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out but the JSON response is not the same format but it works for me.

```
?fields=reactions.type(LIKE).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(like),reactions.type(LOVE).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(love),reactions.type(WOW).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(wow),reactions.type(HAHA).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(haha),reactions.type(SAD).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(sad),reactions.type(ANGRY).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(angry)
```